# Execute query only when user's ip is unique

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I would like to save data to database only once per user, based on his/her IP address. I have a database with the url, date, time and ip list. How can I check if ip already exist and if not - insert data to database, otherwise do nothing? Here's my code so far:

```
<Check if IP already exists in the database - if no - insert:>


$query = "INSERT INTO link (url, date, time, ip) VALUES ('$ref','$date','$time', '$someip')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');

}
else {

echo 'This ip already exists';

}
```

Comment: you could use a ip2long function for storing the IP..that way you can use a smaller int field instead of varchar

Comment: unless you have a real reason for using ip addresses (or you are just practicing), you should instead work with cookies.  many people could be sharing the same ip, so only one of them will be able to execute the query.  alternatively, ip address of a person could change allowing one person to execute the query to be multiple times while denying someone else who gets a "used ip" chance to execute the query at all. Also the first line <Check ..> is not a comment in HTML or PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query your database for a row with a matching ip. You can then use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) to determine how many rows were returned.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
  // IP  does not exist, proceed with insert.
}
```

`127.0.0.1` should obviously be a variable. You can get a users ip with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: This is the clean way to do it, but the solution of @Mark is twice as fast because only one call to the DB is made...

Comment: @Dave to let you know, database timing  isn't in proportion with number of "calls".

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel , I agree on the fact that a query with a join will take much longer then a query on an indexed key. But the bottleneck, for simple calls like the one in this example, is the transfer time of the data from the DB to the app and vice versa.
BTW, the solution here can even be optimized as: "SELECT count(*) FROM link WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1' LIMIT 1" if the result of the query is only used for checking the existence of a record.

Comment: @Dave: why use `LIMIT 1` with `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @Quassnoi that's an optimization in this case because then the query will stop if he found the first item. It's no optimization if there is an unique constraint or index on the ip-table.

Comment: @Dave: there is no such optimization in this query. `LIMIT 1` is applied after the `COUNT(*)` which means it will count all rows then apply the `LIMIT` to the resultset (which contains 1 record anyway).

Comment: @Quassnoi : you are right :-). I confused the `LIMIT` method (used in MySQL and others) with the `ROWNUM` method in Oracle in which one can write: `SELECT count(*) FROM link WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1' AND ROWNUM<= 1`. In that way the selection happens in the where clause and not afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Put an unique index on the ip column. A fault will be returned if a duplicate is inserted. This way you don't need to execute an extra query on the database. Just make sure the error you get back is handled in a correct way (or just ignore the error).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_of_index ON tablename (columns_to_index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on your column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_link_ip ON link (ip)
```

and check for the errors on insert:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO link (url, date, time, ip) VALUES ('$ref','$date','$time', '$someip')";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if (!$res) {
        if (mysql_errno() == 1062) /* unique key violation */
                die('This IP already exists');
        else
                die(mysql_error());
}


}
```